# creating hook for document.location in javascript

Tags: javascript

can we create a reference to document.location property in javascript. From past few days we are working on hooks created on document.createElement. While using this we got a doubt whether we can create a hook on objects like document.location, document.scripts etc.

```
var dbi = document.body.innerHTML; 
document.body.innerHTML=function () { 
    var elem = dbi.apply (document, arguments); 
    console.log(arguments); 
}
```

Comment: Some code showing what you've tried would be awfully helpful.

Comment: `var dbi    = document.body.innerHTML;    
    document.body.innerHTML=function () {   
       var elem = dbi.apply (document, arguments); console.log(arguments);      
        
    }`

Answer (score 3):

In your code:

```
> var dbi = document.body.innerHTML;
```

`innerHTML` is a property whose value is a string, so the value assigned to dbi is a string primitive.

```
> document.body.innerHTML=function () {
```

The body element is a **host object**, there is no reason to believe that you can assign a function object to a property that, according to the relelvant standard, should be a string. It may be possible in some environments, but it can't be depended upon and will fail in at least some browsers in use.

```
>     var elem = dbi.apply (document, arguments);
```

`dbi` is a string primitive, it doesn't have an apply method.

```
>     console.log(arguments);
> }
```

#### Edit

In ES5 you can define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get), e.g.

```
var o = {   
  get pageURI () {   
    return document.location.href;   
  }
}
```

so you can do:

```
alert(o.pageURI);

document.location = document.location.href + '#foo';

alert(o.pageURI);  // current URI with #foo appended
```

but you shouldn't be relying on ES5 on the general web, many browsers don't support it fully yet.

Comment: then how can we create to reference to such objects the above code is not working i just tried it